# When to use malloc, is it really necessary

Tags: c, malloc, free

The malloc example I'm studying is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int *vec;
 int i, size;
 printf("Give size of vector: ");
 scanf("%d",&size);
 vec = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
 for(i=0; i<size; i++) vec[i] = i;
 for(i=0; i<size; i++)
 printf("vec[%d]: %d\n", i, vec[i]);
 free(vec);
}
```

But I can make a program behave at runtime like this program behaves writing it in C wihout malloc, can't I? So what's the use of malloc here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is dynamic memory allocation.

The very important point there is that *you don't know how much memory you'll need* because the amount of memory you must end up with is dependant on the user input.

Thus the use of malloc, which takes `size` as part of its argument, and `size` is unknown at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

This specific example could have been done using [variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c) which were supported by the standard since `c99`, now optional as of the 2011 standard. Although if `size` is very large allocating it on the stack would not work since the stack is much smaller than available heap memory which is what `malloc` will use. This [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16588397) of mine also has some links on variable length arrays you might find useful.

Outside of this example when you have [dynamic data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085018) using `malloc` is pretty hard to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

First, you might not know how much memory you need until run time. Using `malloc()` allows you to allocate exactly the right amount: no more, no less. And your application can "degrade" gracefully if there is not enough memory.

Second, `malloc()` allocated memory from the heap. This can sometimes be an advantage. Local variables that are allocated on the stack have a very limited amount of total memory. Static variables mean that your app will use all the memory all the time, which could even potentially prevent your app from loading if there isn't enough memory.