# Declaring a binary tree in C

Tags: c

In c++ its something like this:

```
struct node{
   int value;
   node *left;
   node *right;
};
```

and in function, when i need it, il use it like this:

```
node *r;
r = new node();
r -> inf = 1;
r -> left = r -> right = null;
```

but how is this working in C ?
i tryed:

```
struct node{
    int value;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

but i got error: indentifier node is undefined, so i changed in:

```
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

but now, if i try to make a new variable:

```
node *r;
```

i get error: identifier node is undefiner at *r declaration line,
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [typedef struct vs struct definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Comment: Doing wrong?  Learning C++ before C, maybe?  Have fun malloc-ing the new nodes, will be waiting for that one :) ... just to prevent another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/4085018/1162141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you refer to your `struct` you must refer to it as:

`struct node * r;`

So your struct definition should look like this:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
}
```

Also, the `new` keyword is not in ANSI C. Since you are working with a pointer, you need to allocate the memory using `malloc()`. So

```
struct node * r = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
r->value = 0;
r->left = NULL;
r->right = NULL;
```

would allocate memory and initialize the records inside.

If you do not want to refer to it as `struct node` as the type, you can use a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
} node;
```

Though you still need to refer the pointers inside the record as `struct node` since it is declared within the `typedef`. Now you can reference as:

```
node * r = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Comment: @simonc You do not de-reference a struct, only variables. `sizeof(node)` is the number of bytes of the record. `sizeof(node*)` is the number of bytes for the pointer. But `sizeof(*node)` is a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

In C (as opposed to C++) you still need to use the struct keyword everywhere (or use a typedef). Try this:

```
struct node *r;
```

or this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;
```

As mentioned in a comment, the node references from inside the struct still need the `struct` keyword, since the typedef does not yet exist. But now you can use node without the `struct` keyword.

Comment: +1. Would also be worth mentioning that `new node()` isn't valid C.

Comment: I think you still need to explicitly specify `struct node` inside the structure declaration for the children pointers.

Comment: You're right, you do still need the struct keyword there. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, you cannot use a `typedef` within the structure being typedefed like suggested by Zach. You need to explicitly name the structure in use :

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}
```

Moreover, I would recommend not to use a `typedef` unless you need to opacify a data type. Typedefing things just for the sake of writing less characters is not a good practice.

Still, if you are really really lazy, the typedef *has* to be done before the struct declaration, as in the example below :

```
/* Note that you can't use the same name for the struct and the typedef */
typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

Then, if you are trying to implement binary trees, you are likely to implement the related methods. You will surely need a reference to the parent of a node to make insertion and deletion easier. Keep it in mind !